# TP-Link TL-WN722N Hostapd

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I'm trying to use a TP-Link TL-WN722N WiFi adapter with Hostapd.
However when I try to start Hostapd I get this messages:

> Configuration file: hostapd.conf
>   nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
>   nl80211 driver initialization failed.
>   hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started

hostapd.conf

> interface=wlan0
>   driver=nl80211
>   ssid=test
>   channel=1

I've tried to apt-get update and upgrade but I still get the same error.
Running Raspbian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this problem by killing wpa_supplicant:

```
killall wpa_supplicant
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bringing wlan0 up manually before starting hostapd? try:

```
sudo ifup wlan0
```